# Python3: Print on a new line while another thread has input open

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, command-line-interface

Python 3.5:

I have some code that looks like this:

```
def printer():
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Output')

thread = threading.Thread(target=printer, args=(), daemon=True)
thread.start()
while True:
    x = input('Input: ')
    #do some work with x
```

When I run this, if I don't actually enter any input, the final output ends up looking like this:

```
Input: Output
```

But I want the 'Output' to always print on a separate line, like this:

```
Input:
Output
```

even if I don't enter anything into Input. As an aside, it's also acceptable if the following happens:

```
Input: #this field can no longer be used
Output
Input:
```

if I don't enter any input.

EDIT: Since I think I didn't make it super clear, if I were in the middle of entering input, I'd want one of the following two cases to happen:

```
Input: foo #I can continue typing on this line
Output
```

or

```
Input: foo #I can't type on this line
Output
Input: #it doesn't matter if 'foo' doesn't reappear here, starting over is okay
```

Comment: How about `x = input('Input: \n')`?

Comment: I do want the input to actually be entered on the same line as Input: in general, but I want this separate thread to print on a different line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because "But I want the 'Output' to always print on a separate line".

I think you can put "\n" before your "output".

Change:

```
print('Output')
```

To:

```
print('\nOutput')
```

Comment: I don't think it solves the problem, because 'input' won't be printed a second time. It's only going to be printed once.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I think the problem Freddy want to solve is print output in a new line. If you want a new "Input" in another line. In fact you can put an "\nInput" after "output" , or create a new input script after output.

Comment: He explicitly has two 'input' strings in the required output ... But if he likes your answer, I guess it's god enough.

Comment: Anyway, I agree with your serious attitude.